# Omniauth Facebook doesnt return the extra data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth-facebook

I tried with everything that show up in google or here but doesn't work 
its just show me the basic info (name,id,photo)

here s my code for omniauth.rb:

```
provider :facebook, 'key', 'key', {:scope => 'email',:info_fields => 'email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
```

and this is how i call it:

```
auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
session[:omniauth] = auth
```

Comment: try to remove `:scope => 'email'`

Comment: dont work :C, but thanks

Comment: can you fetch something if use just `provider :facebook, 'key', 'key'` ?

Comment: i put the real keys in the api i put

Comment: you didn't understand me. Can you try use just `provider :facebook, 'key', 'key'`, without `{:scope => 'email',:info_fields => 'email', :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}`. What do you get in response?

Comment: i get the basic info

Comment: and what exactly information do you need?

Comment: all the extra info, like gender, age, email, birthday, first_name, last_name

Comment: strange, as I know if you do not point scope, you should fetch all open information. Sorry...

Comment: its okay, thanks you anyway

Comment: emm but doesnt matter if the app is on development or no?(in the facebook development page)